# Move project into subdirectory

Tags: git

I have a git repository in a directory called `project`:

```
[~/project]$ ls
a  b  c
```

I want to move everything into a subdirectory of the `project` directory, so it look like this:

```
[~/project]$ ls
subdir
[~/project]$ cd subdir
[~/project/subdir]$ ls
a  b  c
```

Normally a `git mv` would work, but I want to make it look as if the historical commits had always been made to that subdirectory from the beginning. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why would you like to change history? The whole point of git or any other source code management system is to keep the history intact.

Comment: @piokuc: I'm merging one git repository into another. It would break `bisect` if I didn't do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like `filter-branch` does what I want:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter \
        'mkdir subdir; \
        find -maxdepth 1 \
            -not -name . \
            -not -name .git \
            -not -name subdir \
            -print0 \
        | xargs -0 -I{} mv {} subdir' \
    -d /tmp/whatever -- --all
```

The `-d /tmp/whatever` part is just so it runs the commands on a tmpfs filesystem so there isn't a bunch of disk IO.

(In rare cases, `/tmp` won't be mounted as tmpfs. You can check with `mount | grep tmp`.)

Comment: I put everything on different lines, but I went one further and used `/dev/shm` versus `/tmp` given your stated intention. It is not a given that `/tmp` will be `tmpfs` whereas, with `/dev/shm` it is. But the downside is that it's always true `/tmp` will be there, but depending on the *nix distribution, it's remotely possible `/dev/shm` will not be there. I just used this myself and it works great.

Comment: Only problem so far, is that this requires a local clone that's not `bare` :-/

Comment: @digitalextremist: Thanks for the formatting! I personally prefer `/tmp` because it's available on *BSD and OS X, so I rolled back that particular edit.

Comment: Roger that. I'm fighting with a customized version of this, here: https://github.com/digitalextremist/omnirepo/blob/master/bin/omnirepo#L160 and have sort of a catch-22... if I mirror/bare-clone a repository, there is no working tree to use `find` on... and for some reason, after the first branch is processed, all the others fail because now the directory created in the `--tree-filter` block exists already...

Comment: I didn't look at your code too carefully, but could you clone the bare repo into a temp directory, run filter-branch, then push back up to the bare repo?

Comment: The repo I originally used this on only had one branch, but it looks like you should only need to run this on one branch even if you have multiple branches in your repo. The rev-list --all option will give you the head of every branch and traverse the object graph from there.

Comment: That's what I've been trying :)